# Extra padding in Chrome and Safari

Tags: safari, google-chrome, padding, margins

Safari and Chrome seem to be adding extra padding/margins in regards to the text within the boxes at one of the [pages within my website](http://www.smsusyd.com/about-us/2010-executive-team/).  What can I do to make it appear the same way it does in Firefox and IE?

Comment: The code at your URL is likely to change, you should narrow down the problem and post the relevant code to duplicate it in your question.  (But I see this is already answered below, so do this in the future.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an orphaned closing `</p>` tag after the link in `.box`es. Chrome/Safari add an opening tag; Firefox/IE simply ignore it. You should remove the tag.

Comment: Thanks. Chrome seems to automatically add the closing tag if no <p> is added. I added the opening tag, but it still appears the same.

Comment: Oh wait! I adjusted the margins and it's all good now for all browsers. Thanks!